# last child click doesnt change

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I select box `2`, I'd like the border to become black.
Another click it should go back to yellow.

The first click goes right but the second click stays black.
I can fix this by adding another class, but I don't want to.

How else can I do this?

This is my code:

```
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">1</div>
    <div class="cc"></div>
</div>
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">2</div>
    <div class="cc"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('.bb:last').addClass('yellow');

$('.bb').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.cc').fadeToggle();

    if (!$('.cc:last').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.bb:last').addClass('black');
    } else {
        $('.bb:last').removeClass('black');
        $('.bb:last').addClass('yellow');
    }
});
```

```
.bb {
    background:red;
    width:90px;
    height:30px
}

.cc {
    background:blue;
    width:90px;
    height:30px;
    display:none;
}

.yellow {
    border:3px solid yellow;
}
.black {
    border:3px solid black;
}
```

Sample [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M5BdH/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5BdH/2/)

You basically need to remove the class if it has it.

```
$('.bb:last').addClass('yellow');

$('.bb').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.cc').fadeToggle();
    if (!$('.cc:last').is(':hidden')) {
        if ($('.bb:last').hasClass('black')) {
            $('.bb:last').removeClass('black');
        } else {
            $('.bb:last').addClass('black');
        }
    } else {
        $('.bb:last').addClass('yellow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! `hasClass`, never known before.

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M5BdH/5/)**</kbd>

```
$('.bb:last').addClass('yellow');
$('.bb').click(function( e ) {   
    $(this).next('.cc').fadeToggle();
    if(e.target == $('.bb:last')[0])
        $(this).toggleClass('yellow black');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/
http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: @PSCoder that means we both like simplicity :)

Comment: You should store `$(this)` in a variable, instead of initalizing jQuery three times.

Comment: This code is broken.  If you watch in a debugger, the div ends up with class `bb yellow yellow, black`, which only works coincidentally.  `.toggleClass()` takes a *space*-separated list, without commas.  Additionally, you don't need the `.hasClass()` check.

Comment: @JeffB you're totally true, I don't know why i memorized that it had to be a comma in there. Thanks now I made it even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution.  Just use `.toggleClass('yellow black')`.  `toggleClass()` will take care of everything for you.  Any class in the space-separated list that is set will be cleared, and vice versa.  To affect only the last `.bb` you could put it in it's own handler:

```
$('.bb:last').addClass('yellow').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('yellow black');
});
$('.bb').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.cc').fadeToggle();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/8MbKU/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: In your demo the first element goes crazy with classes and borders, I'm afraid it's not what the OP needs.

Comment: Goes crazy? Maybe I'm not clear on what the OP wants.  If they don't want the first one to change border style, it's easy enough, as you showed in your example.  You could also use a separate handler, as in my updated example.